# Initial offset of number of posts in home page on the posts page

Tags: php, html

I've got a problem.

Im using WP_query on my static home page, and i've set up an 'archive' page (not like archives/tags etc) as my 'page 2' which has all my other posts on it.

My home page is a total of 13 posts, but I was wondering, on the 'archive' page, how do you offset those 13 posts without explicitly implying 'offset' => 13 in wp_query? It gives me the same results for each archive page I go to.

So I was wondering, is there an 'initial offset' I could use on the archives page?

Comment: [See *Making Custom Queries using Offset and Pagination* in Codex for an explanation and solution](https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be to set `posts_per_page` for the query to 13 and then override the `$paged` global (before the query is called) to force it to 2 if it is only 1... eg.

```
if ( (is_post_type_archive('post')) {
     global $paged;
     if ( ($paged == 0) || ($paged == 1) ) {$paged = 2;}
}
```

Comment: @patkay Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)